# Building a JSON string that contains an array of JSON strings

Tags: php, json

In PHP I am trying to put together a JSON string that gets returned with the status of the takes and any errors that may have occurred:

```
public function create() {
    $data = Validate::sanitize($_POST['data']);
    parse_str($data);

    // Something

    $this->JSONResponse[] = $this->addCost($shipmentId, $cost);

    $this->JSONResponse[] = '{"code":"0", "type":"info", msg":"Shipment created successfully."}';
    return '{"response":['.json_encode($this->JSONResponse).']}';
}

public function addCost($shipmentId, $cost) {
    if ($cost > 0) {
        // Something
    } else {
        return '{"code":"1", "type":"info", msg":"Cost not added as it was 0 or left out."}';
    }
}
```

The ways I have tried including the one in the above example don't work. I either get a string that isn't JSON or a JSON object consisting of indexes containing the raw JSON string.

How can I get this to output what I want?

Comment: in both your cases you are creating `msg"`, this should be `"msg"`.  All json properties must be enclosed by quotes unless they are numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you're writing the `JSON` string manually instead of **building a PHP `array` and taking advantage of the `json_encode` function**?

If not you should use

```
public function addCost($shipmentId, $cost) {
    if ($cost > 0) {
        // Something
    } else {
        return json_encode(array("code"=>1, "type"=>"info", "msg"=>"message"));
    }
}
```

And as Kami said, ther's a typo here :

```
'{"code":"0", "type":"info", msg":"Shipment created successfully."}';
```

It lacks a "

```
'{"code":"0", "type":"info", "msg":"Shipment created successfully."}';
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't see the typo but building it as an array instead of a string is much nicer and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create the string by hand - create a PHP object or array - and then use `json_encode` to create a string out of it.  Something like this:

```
public function create() {
    $data = Validate::sanitize($_POST['data']);
    parse_str($data);

    // Something

    $this->JSONResponse[] = $this->addCost($shipmentId, $cost);

    $this->JSONResponse[] = json_encode(array("code" => 0,
                                              "type" => "info",
                                              "msg"  => "Shipment created successfully."));
    return json_encode(array("response" => $this->JSONResponse[]));
}

public function addCost($shipmentId, $cost) {
    if ($cost > 0) {
        // Something
    } else {
        return array("code" => 1,
                     "type" => "info"
                     "msg"  => "Cost not added as it was 0 or left out.");
    }
}
```